# Aptana fatal: Unable to create '.git/index.lock': File exists

Tags: git, aptana, aptana3

I'm using Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.3.1.201212171919 with GIT.  After using it for a while I've been noticing that when performing GIT operations, Aptana is constantly refreshing my workspace which in turn is locking my GIT repo for minutes at a time.  If I try to perform any GIT operation that needs the index file locked while Aptana is refreshing I get the below

```
fatal: Unable to create 'c:/wamp/www/website/.git/index.lock': File exists.

If no other git process is currently running, this probably means a
git process crashed in this repository earlier. Make sure no other git
process is running and remove the file manually to continue.
```

I've created a ticket with them here https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-7603

Has anyone found a way to prevent this from happening/taking so long/not creating the lock

## EDIT

I was able to at least temporarily fix this. When under the "App Explorer" within the repo using GIT. Click the blue gears. In the dropdown hover "more" click "disconnect" this will stop Aptana from monitoring the GIT repo for changes. GIT will still work but I no longer get Aptana trying to refresh my workspace and visually the file tree will not show changes anymore.

## EDIT 2

performing an `rm` on the index.lock file will not solve this issue.  My issue is that when Aptana is building the workspace it keeps creating and removing the index.lock file for its processes which GIT operations need. If I watch the .git folder I can see the index.lock file being created and removed by Aptana. Once Aptana is done the index.lock file is gone and I can perform operations fine so there is no need to remove it.

Answer (score 1):

try `rm -f ./.git/index.lock` because in the rare instance that git crashed... this file gets jacked.

Comment: no...see comment [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13992481/aptana-fatal-unable-to-create-git-index-lock-file-exists#comment-21038338)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

The only solution is to run the Git command twice. Then the lock file is unlocked

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  Mine gets locked up for sometimes 5 minutes no matter how many times I try to run my command.  Randomly I will be able to sneak in between the refresh and my command will run.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still getting this problem please try

rm c:/wamp/www/website/.git/index.lock

it works for me.

Comment: This will not solve my issue.  My issue is that when Aptana is building the workspace it keeps creating and removing the index.lock file for its processes which GIT operations need.  If I watch the `.git` folder I can see the index.lock file being created and removed by Aptana.  Once Aptana is done the index.lock file is gone and I can perform operations fine so there is no need to remove it.